# Как в django ORM filter __in сделать выборку по списку кортежей?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

В результате должен получиться подобный запрос:

```sql
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM mytable
WHERE (field1, field2) IN(
    (1, 1), 
    (2, 2)
);
```

django==1.9.13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177749/django-filter-queryset-on-tuples-of-values-for-multiple-columns

Comment: @5c0rp Это оно! Скопируй ответ сюда, помечу лучшим.